# Change Blog Post Layout of Frappe Framework

Tags: erpnext, frappe

how to modify the layout of Blog Post in a secure way?
so when there’s an update, the changes won’t be gone.

I’m talking about the template in here: `apps/frappe/frappe/website/doctype/blog_post/templates/blog_post.html`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an app and you can specify blog template in hooks.py of your app.

In bench folder issue:

```
bench new-app my_blog_template
nano apps/my_blog_template
```

Add

```
base_template_map = {
    r"blogs.*": "app/templates/blog_template.html"
}
```

And construct your new template in app/templates/blog_template.html file.

That way you don't change any file in frappe or erpnext. So you are free to upgrade. All customizations will be in your app.

Source: https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/python-api/hooks#base-template

Comment: hi @turker could you explain more about your method?
the base_template_map has to be inserted into hooks.py of the new app isn't it?

so i've done this, and i copied the content of `frappe/website/doctype/blog_post/templates/blog_post.html` into `my_blog_template/templates/blog_template.html` and tweak the layout a bit, but it seems not working

is there any action need to do in order to apply this change?
fyi, i've set the site into `"developer_mode": 1` already via site_config.json

Comment: Did you try this: bench clear-cache && bench restart

Comment: Yes, I tried both, but apparently this method is changing the base template on the whole, what I'm trying to do is to change the blog_post.html template only

Comment: What is exact url of your blog page?

Comment: my full url will be: website.com/blog/promotions/chinese-new-year-premium-promotion

here is the screenshot of the admin panel: https://prnt.sc/26ojxib

Comment: Did you try     r"blog*": "app/templates/blog_template.html" ?